# Clicking a list item within another list item Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1ozc7uqr/

Trying to show a `<p>` when I click each list item, list items can have a list in them.

Problem is when a nested `<li>` is clicked its parents `<p>` shows.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="list">
<li>Item 1
    <p>>> Item 1 P</p>
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1.1
            <p>>> Item 1.1 P</p>
        </li>
        <li>Item 1.2
            <p>>> Item 1.2 P</p>
        </li>
        <li>Item 1.3
            <p>>> Item 1.3 P</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>Item 2
    <p>>> Item 2 P</p>
</li>
<li>Item 3
    <p>>> Item 3 P</p>
</li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".list li").click(function () {
      $(this).find("p").eq(0).toggle();
   });
});
```

Comment: Please post your code here, not just as a fiddle link.

Comment: And don't post collaboration fiddles.

Comment: Technically when you are clicking a child li you are clicking the parent li as well, and so both events are being triggered.

Comment: Use `event.StopPropagation()` to prevent the event from bubbling out to the containing elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Barmar has suggested, use `event.stopPropagation()` to prevent the event from bubbling up the DOM to the parent `li` element.

http://jsfiddle.net/1ozc7uqr/3/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".list li").click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).find("p").eq(0).toggle();
    });
});
```

Also, if you want to put `>` in your HTML, use `&gt;` to conform to standards.